# Is it possible to use the JSONObject 'put' method and keep capitalized the parameter name?

Tags: java, json

While testing an API from Java I am using the JSONObject 'put' method to add entries to the JSON body of an HTTP request. The value that I am passing to the 'put' method contains other objects, some of which have attributes with capitalized names (see example below). I know instance variables are expected to have Camel-case but the winMethod object that I'm receiving in the players array doesn't comply with this.
When I pass the object to the 'put' method, it appears to **convert the attributes names to lower case** (i.e. from "Enabled" to "enabled"). Since this body is sent to an external API which expect those attributes capitalized, it is failing since it does not recognize those elements.
Is there any way to preserve the case of the parameters passed to the 'put' method?

I'm adding elements to JSON body like this:

```
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();    
jsonBody.put("actionType", "Start");
jsonBody.put("playerCount", 1);
jsonBody.put("players",     playersArray);
```

This is how the body is expected (note the capitalized EffectiveDate and Enabled fields):

```
{
  "actionType": "Start",
  "playerCount": 1,
  "players": [
               {
                 "gameType": "Cheque",
                 "winMethods": [
                                 {
                                   "winMethod": "SEARCH",
                                   "EffectiveDate": "2019-03-22 10:22:22",
                                   "Enabled": "Y"
                                 }
                               ],
                 "playerId": "88881"
               }
             ]
}
```

Comment: I am using this library very often and didn't have this issue. Are you using the library on Android or other java app? What version of the library?

Comment: The JSONObject library does not capitalize anything.  This is a bug elsewhere in your code.  Note that you didn't give us the code that actually set these fields.